# Economics.SE is closing, some questions could be migrated

Tags: discussion, migration

[Economics.SE is closing on 4 May](https://economics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/159/economics-is-closing) and I, along with the other mods, am in the process of salvaging the best questions we have to be migrated to other parts of the SE universe where they may make a good fit.

We have had a request to transfer a question across and I will be doing so.

https://economics.stackexchange.com/q/99/48

I realise I should ask in advance, but we have very little time and I feel it worthwhile having the discussion of relevance/appropriateness once we have the luxury of having actually saved them.

If you would like to [review other questions on the site](https://economics.stackexchange.com/), please, we can use the help.

Thanks.

Comment: This question is fine for our board.

Comment: This would fit

[How to get the data to reproduce a published result][1]


  [1]: http://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/309/how-to-get-the-data-to-reproduce-a-published-result

Comment: See also this [general migration thread on meta.econ.SE](http://meta.economics.stackexchange.com/questions/165/salvaging-questions-by-migration).

Comment: So, did Economics reopen again after this? If so, this should might fit the criteria for being closed as obsolete.

Comment: What happened to it?! Was it not economically viable? :P

Answer (score 1):

Here are some other candidates for migration:

- [Are European Eductional Institutions Experiencing the Same Amount of Price Increases as American Schools?](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/487/are-european-eductional-institutions-experiencing-the-same-amount-of-price-incre)
- [Are there any open-source textbooks on economics freely available on the web?](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/894/are-there-any-open-source-textbooks-on-economics-freely-available-on-the-web)

Comment: I've posted these and the one listed above on [their meta](http://meta.economics.stackexchange.com/questions/173/questions-relevant-to-academia-se).